# Searching an array for number of occurrences

Tags: c++

This code is supposed to display a menu with 6 options. create new file, display numbers, total, and average, display a sort, search for a num and tell yow how many occurrences it had, append random numbers, and display largest.

It runs and does MOST of what it is supposed to do but I just CANNOT get the `searchNum` function to search for the number entered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void menu();
string createFile();
void displayNumTotalAverage(string myFileName);
void displaySortedNums(string myFileName);
void searchNum(string myFileName);
void displayLargestNum(string myFileName);
void appendRandomNum(string myFileName);

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    string myFileName = "";

    do
    {
        cout << "** MENU **" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Current Data File: ";
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint;
        menu();

        cin >> choice;

        while (choice < 1 || choice > 7)
        {
            cout << "Menu Choice: ";
            cin >> choice;
            cout << endl;
        }
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            myFileName = createFile();
            break;
            case 2:
            displayNumTotalAverage(myFileName);
            break;
            case 3:
            displaySortedNums(myFileName);
            break;
            case 4:
            searchNum(myFileName);
            break;
            case 5:
            displayLargestNum(myFileName);
            break;
            case 6:
            appendRandomNum(myFileName);
            break;
        }

    } while (choice != 7);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void menu()
{
    cout << "\n\n(1)  Select / create data file(.txt file extension will be       added automatically)\n"
         << "(2)  Display all numbers, total, and average\n(3)  Display all numbers sorted\n(4)  "
         << "Search for a number and display how many times it occurs\n(5)  Display the largest number\n"
         << "(6)  Append a random number(s)\n(7)  Exit the program\n\nMenu Choice:";
}
string createFile()
{

    string myFileName;
    ifstream inFile;

    cout << "\nName of data file: ";
    cin >> myFileName;

    inFile.open(myFileName);
    if (inFile)
    {
        cout << myFileName;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nFile not found, creating file.\n\n";
        ofstream outFile;
        outFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return myFileName;
}

void displayNumTotalAverage(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;

    const int SIZE = 50;
    int num[SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;
    double average = 0;

    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    while (!inFile)
        cout << "\nData File is empty" << endl << endl;

    while (count < SIZE && inFile >> num[count])
        count++;

    inFile.close();
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        cout << num[index] << endl;
        total += num[index];
    }
    average = (float)total / count;
    cout << endl << "Total  :  " << total << endl << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << average << endl << endl;
    cout << "File Successfully Read" << endl << endl;


    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}


void displaySortedNums(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    if(inFile.good())
    {
        const int SIZE = 50;
        int num[SIZE]; int counter = 0;
        while (counter < SIZE && inFile >> num[counter])
            counter++;
        inFile.close();
        for(int idx1 = 0; idx1 < counter; ++idx1)
            for(int idx2 = idx1; idx2 < counter; ++idx2)
                if(num[idx1] > num[idx2])
                {
                    int tmp = num[idx1];
                    num[idx1] = num[idx2];
                    num[idx2] = tmp;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                {
                    cout << num[i] << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}

void searchNum(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(myFileName + "txt");
    const int SIZE = 50;
    int num[SIZE];
    bool found = false;
    int position = -1;
    int index = 0;
    int userNum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int numCount = 0;
    cout << "Search Number: ";
    cin >> userNum;
    cout << endl << endl;
    while (index < SIZE && !found)
    {
        if (num[index] == userNum)
        {
            found = true;
            position = index;
            numCount++;
        }

        index++;
    }

    cout << userNum << " occurs " << numCount << " times ";
    cout << "File Successfully Read\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}

void displayLargestNum(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    const int SIZE = 50;
    int nums[SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    int highest;
    while (count < SIZE && inFile >> nums[count])
        count++;
    highest = nums[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] > highest)
            highest = nums[count];
    }
    cout << "\nLargest Number:  " << highest << endl << "File Successfully            Read" << endl << endl;
}

void appendRandomNum(string myFileName)
{
    cout << "i am in the appendRandomNum function - option 6" << endl;
    int num = 0;
    int count = 0;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(myFileName + ".txt", ios::app);
    cout << "How many random numbers: ";
    cin >> count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        outFile << rand() % 10 << endl;
    outFile.close();
    cout << endl << "Number(s) Added" << endl << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return;
}
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: my display largest number function is not working properly either....

Comment: In what ways do they fail?  Does it produce an error and crash, are you getting bad results?  Please be specific.  Providing an input, output, and expected output is very helpful.

Comment: in `void searchNum(string myFileName)` function,you are searching `num` array but where are you populating it?

Comment: I am trying to search an array that is composed of numbers from a file. you can even use the append random function to load it up with up to 50 random numbers, then search those for the userNum you enter.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 problems in searchNum function:

1. The file is opened but num array is not populated with the file content
2. numCount will always return either 0 or 1. Remove 'found' boolean variable altogether and it will then return the correct numCount value.

Comment: 1. I see what u mean..I guess i have so many similar functions I thought i had done it to this part but had not. I thinkk I can fix this.

Comment: so i need to add a line like this one??  while (count < SIZE && inFile >> nums[count])

Comment: You need to add:
while (index < SIZE && inFile >> nums[index])
{
if (num[index] == userNum)
  numCount++;
index++;
}

Answer (score 1):

Here are some important rules they never seem to teach in programming courses: start with something small and simple that works, add complexity a little at a time, and develop new functionality in isolation.

Suppose you have the rest of the code working perfectly, and you can produce a file called `nums.txt` that looks like this:

```
7
9 
3
8
0
2
4
8
3
9
```

Now you want to develop and test the `searchNum` function. So you write a `main` function like this:

```
int main()
{
  string myFileName = "nums";
  searchNum(myFileName);
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Then a `searchNum` function:

```
void searchNum(string myFileName)
{
}
```

You compile and run this, it does nothing, **so far so good.**

Now have it open the file, read the first number and display it:

```
void searchNum(string myFileName)
{
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(myFileName + "txt");

  int num;
  inFile >> num;
  cout << num << endl;
}
```

So far so good. Now iterate through the whole file:

```
void searchNum(string myFileName)
{
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(myFileName + "txt");

  int num;
  while(inFile >> num)
  {
    cout << num << endl;
  }
}
```

So far so good. Now count the 8's:

```
void searchNum(string myFileName)
{
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(myFileName + "txt");

  int num;
  int count = 0;
  while(inFile >> num)
  {
    cout << num << endl;
    if(num == 8)
      ++count;
  }
}
```

You get the idea. Using this approach you'll get clean working code, and you'll get it faster than by trying to write it all and then fix all the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I noticed also in `searchNum`
`inFile.open(myFileName + "txt");` should be `inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");`, a dot is missing from the suffix.

Read the rest of the answers and get acquainted with the debugger it will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Here is your code sample with the needed corrections. Keep up the good work and invest some time for the use of a debugger.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void menu();
string createFile();
void displayNumTotalAverage(string myFileName);
void displaySortedNums(string myFileName);
void searchNum(string myFileName);
void displayLargestNum(string myFileName);
void appendRandomNum(string myFileName);

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    string myFileName = "";

    do
    {
        cout << "** MENU **" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Current Data File: " << myFileName << (!myFileName.empty() ? ".txt" : "");
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint;

        menu();

        cin >> choice;

        while (choice < 1 || choice > 7)
        {
            cout << "Menu Choice: ";
            cin >> choice;
            cout << endl;
        }
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                myFileName = createFile();
                break;
            case 2:
                displayNumTotalAverage(myFileName);
                break;
            case 3:
                displaySortedNums(myFileName);
                break;
            case 4:
                searchNum(myFileName);
                break;
            case 5:
                displayLargestNum(myFileName);
                break;
            case 6:
                appendRandomNum(myFileName);
                break;
        }

    } while (choice != 7);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
void menu()
{
    cout << "\n\n(1)  Select / create data file(.txt file extension will be       added automatically)\n"
        << "(2)  Display all numbers, total, and average\n(3)  Display all numbers sorted\n(4)  "
        << "Search for a number and display how many times it occurs\n(5)  Display the largest number\n"
        << "(6)  Append a random number(s)\n(7)  Exit the program\n\nMenu Choice:";
}

string createFile()
{

    string myFileName;
    ifstream inFile;

    cout << "\nName of data file: ";
    cin >> myFileName;

    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt", std::ifstream::in);

    if (inFile)
    {
        cout << myFileName;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nFile not found, creating file.\n\n";
        ofstream outFile;
        outFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
        outFile.close();
    }

    cin.get();

    return myFileName;
}

void displayNumTotalAverage(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;

    const int SIZE = 50;
    int num[SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;
    double average = 0;

    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    while (!inFile)
        cout << "\nData File is empty" << endl << endl;

    while (count < SIZE && inFile >> num[count])
        count++;

    inFile.close();
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        cout << num[index] << endl;
        total += num[index];
    }
    average = (float)total / count;
    cout << endl << "Total  :  " << total << endl << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << average << endl << endl;
    cout << "File Successfully Read" << endl << endl;


    cin.get();
    return;
}


void displaySortedNums(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    if(inFile.good()) 
    {
        const int SIZE = 50; 
        int num[SIZE]; int counter = 0; 
        while (counter < SIZE && inFile >> num[counter])         
            counter++;
        inFile.close();
        for(int idx1 = 0; idx1 < counter; ++idx1) 
            for(int idx2 = idx1; idx2 < counter; ++idx2) 
                if(num[idx1] > num[idx2])
                {
                    int tmp = num[idx1]; 
                    num[idx1] = num[idx2];  
                    num[idx2] = tmp; 
                }
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            cout << num[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return;
}

void searchNum(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    const int SIZE = 50;
    int num[SIZE];
    int position = -1;
    int index = 0; 
    int userNum = 0; 
    int counter = 0;
    int numCount = 0;
    cout << "Search Number: ";
    cin >> userNum;
    cout << endl << endl;

    // Fill num array with inFile numbers.
    while (counter < SIZE && inFile >> num[counter++]);

    while (index < SIZE)
    {
        if (num[index] == userNum)
        {
            position = index;
            numCount++;
        }

        index++;
    }

    cout << userNum << " occurs " << numCount << " times ";
    cout << "File Successfully Read\n\n";
    cin.get();
    return;
}

void displayLargestNum(string myFileName)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(myFileName + ".txt");
    const int SIZE = 50;
    int nums[SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    int highest;
    while (count < SIZE && inFile >> nums[count])
        count++;
    highest = nums[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] > highest)
            highest = nums[count];
    }
    cout << "\nLargest Number:  " << highest << endl << "File Successfully            Read" << endl << endl;

}

void appendRandomNum(string myFileName)
{
    cout << "i am in the appendRandomNum function - option 6" << endl;
    int count = 0;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(myFileName + ".txt", ios::app);
    cout << "How many random numbers: ";
    cin >> count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        outFile << rand() % 10 << endl;
    outFile.close();
    cout << endl << "Number(s) Added" << endl << endl;

    cin.get();

    return;
}
```

Comment: OMG You are my hero right now!!! =D   I am a computer science major and this my first actual programming class. (My school has a lot of emphasis on the calculus and physics, and not some much on the actal PROGRAMMING courses. So I took my intro programming, and this this was our project, but we havent actually learned the debugger yet. Apparently thats for next class.the object oriented programming...Thanks so much, i cant wait to print out the fixes u made and compare them with mine, so i can really see how it should have been done, I think I was as close I was going to get on my own. THANK U